# How does Haskell choose methods for instances of type classes?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I was trying to understand why Haskell's `show` treats
a list of chars different from a list of e.g. integers
even without the `FlexibleInstances` Pragma.

Having read through the documentation of `Show`, I realized
that I don't really understand how Haskell chooses methods
for instances of type classes.

Consider the following code:

```
class MyShow a where
    myShow :: a -> String
    myShowList :: [a] -> String
    myShowTuple :: (a, b) -> String

    myShowList xs = "Default List Implementation"
    myShowTuple t = "Default Tuple Implementation"

instance MyShow Char where
    myShow c = "One Char"
    myShowList xs = "List of Chars"
    myShowTuple t = "Char Tuple"

instance MyShow Int where
    myShow n = "One Int"
    myShowList xs = "List of Integers"
    myShowTuple t = "Int Tuple"

instance MyShow Float where
    myShow n = show n

instance (MyShow a) => MyShow [a] where
    myShow = myShowList

instance (MyShow a) => MyShow (a, b) where
    myShowTuple t = "foo"
    myShow = myShowTuple
```

Now if I call e.g.

```
myShow (5::Int,5::Int)
```

I would expect that Haskell thinks
'Oh, `myShow` got a tuple as an argument. Let's see which
implementation I have to call.'
and chooses the last one which in return would result
in `"foo"`.
Obviously, this is not the case.
Haskell seems to look at the content of the tuple (namely
the type of `a`) and decides to call the corresponding method,
resulting in `"Int Tuple"`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write `myShow (5::Int, 5::Int)`, Haskell *does* say "Oh, myShow got a tuple as an argument. Let's see which implementation I have to call." and it *does* choose the last one, i.e. `myShow = myShowTuple`. But that doesn't mean the result will be "foo". It means that the result of calling `myShow (5::Int, 5::Int)` will be the same as the result of calling `myShowTuple (5 :: Int, 5 :: Int)`.

So now Haskell has to decide which version of `myShowTuple` it has to call. Since `myShowTuple` has type `MyShow a => (a, b) -> String`, the version of `myShowTuple` that's defined on the second-to-last line has type `MyShow a => ((a, c), b) -> String`, so that one doesn't fit. The one defined on line 17 has type `(Int, b) -> String`, so that one does fit. So that's the one that is picked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand why `myShowTuple` on the second-to-last line has type `((a, c), b)` as tuples aren't the only instance of MyShow.

Comment: @Aton (Renaming type variables to avoid ambiguity). Because inside the class definition of `MyShow t` you have `myShowTuple :: (t, t2) -> String` and on the second to last line, you're in the instance definition for `MyShow (a,b)`, so `t` is `(a,b)`, thus `(t, t2) -> String` becomes `((a,b), t2) -> String`.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell's thought process is something like this:

1. It tries to figure out the instance of `MyShow` for `(5 :: Int, 5 :: Int)` or `(Int, Int)`
2. It then finds the instance `MyShow a => MyShow (a, b)`
3. Since this unifies, (`a` => `a` and `b` => `a`) it selects this instance.
4. It checks to make sure `a`, in this case `Int`, is also an instance of `MyShow`, which it is. Notice: This check happens **after** the instance is selected.
5. `myShow (5 :: Int, 5 :: Int)` call's the tuple's `myShow` and becomes `myShowTuple (5 :: Int, 5 :: Int)`

   - It doesn't call `myShowTuple` since this has the type `(a, b)` and in the tuple's case, `a` is `(a, b)` so `myShowTuple` has the type `((a, b) ,c)` which is clearly not a match.
6. This has the type `MyShow a => (a, b) -> String)` and since `a` in this case has the type `Int` haskell resolves this to the `Int` instance of `MyShow`
7. It runs the appropriate `myShowTuple`
8. You get `"Int Tuple"`

Just a sidenote, if this was an actual implementation of `Show` you'd want something like this for `myShowTuple`

```
myShowTuple :: MyShow b => (a, b) -> String
```

Otherwise you have no way to actual format that `b` which is after all, any type.

This would make

```
instance (MyShow a) => MyShow (a, b) where
  ...
```

into

```
instance (MyShow a, MyShow b) => MyShow (a, b) where
  ...
```